# error openxlsx can only read .xlsx files When loading .xlsx files

Tags: r, excel, openxlsx

I’m getting this error every time I load my excel files into R:

> error openxlsx can only read .xlsx files

. However, all the files are `.xlsx` files and data looks like it loads ok. But as I’m new to R I'm not sure if I am safe to ignore this error and just treat it as a warning.

I have installed and loaded `readxls` & `openxlsx` libraries.

Comment: If you get the data you're looking for into R, with the correct formatting and everything, then I'd say it works and to just treat it as an error. Take this advice with caution, obviously!

Comment: Thanks very much, good to see someone else thinks the same if it’s not broken…..